# Remove 'k' consecutive same characters from a string until the string doesn't have any consecutive characters

Tags: string

Remove `'k'` consecutive same characters from a string until the string doesn't have any consecutive characters.

```
example :- abbac k->2
 in first iteration b's will be removed -> aac
 in second iteration a's will be removed -> c
so output is -> c
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using here?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This isn't a free coding service. Please take the [tour], and especially read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and add the code you've tried so far. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
string removeDuplicates(string str, int k) {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout.tie(NULL);
    stack<pair<char,int> >s;
    for(int i=0;i<str.size();i++)
    {
        if(s.empty())s.push({str[i],1});
        else{
            
            if(s.top().first==str[i]){
                ++s.top().second;
                if(s.top().second==k){s.pop();}
            }
            else {s.push({str[i],1});}             
        }
    }
    string res="";
    while(!s.empty())
    {
        int x=s.top().second;
        while(x--)
            res=s.top().first+res;
        s.pop();
    }
    return res;
}};
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include an explanation of how this answers the question so people can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

One regex based approach would be to iterate and keep replacing the pattern `(.)\1+` with empty string, until the length of the input string stops getting smaller, which would imply that no more duplicates can be removed.  Here is a working script in Java:

```
String input = "abbac";
int lastLength;
do {
    lastLength = input.length();
    input = input.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "");
} while (input.length() < lastLength);
System.out.println(input);
```

The output here is just `c`.

If you want to control the number of replacements based on an input `k`, then just use a `for` loop instead:

```
String input = "abbac";
int k = 3;
for (int i=0; i < k; ++i) {
    input = input.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "");
}
```

Comment: see if k=3 the string will be as it is ->abbac

Comment: @ashutoshyelgulwar Sorry, I missed the requirement on `k` which controls the number of replacements, q.v. my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
string Reduced_String(long long k, string a){

    stack<pair<char,int>> s;
    int count=0;
    int i,x,n=a.size();
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(s.size())
        {
            pair<char,int> p=s.top();
            if(a[i]==p.first)
            {
                count=p.second+1;
            }
            else
            {
                count=1;
            }
            
            s.push({a[i],count});
        }
        else
        {
            count=1;
            s.push({a[i],count});
        }
        
        pair<char,int> p=s.top();
        
        if(p.second>=k)
        {
            x=k;
            while(x--)
            {
                s.pop();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    string ans="";
    
    while(s.size())
    {
        pair<char,int> p=s.top();
        ans.push_back(p.first);
        s.pop();
    }

    reverse(ans.begin(), ans.end());
    
    return and;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string remove_K_Consecutive_Identical_Characters(string s,int k){
stack<pair<char,int> > st;
for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
    if(st.empty() || st.top().first!=s[i]){
        st.push({s[i],1});
    }
    else if(st.top().first==s[i]){
        pair<char,int> p=st.top();
        st.pop();
        p.second+=1;
        st.push(p);
        if(st.top().second==k){
            st.pop();
        }
    }
}
string result="";
while(!st.empty()){
    pair<char,int> p=st.top();
    for(int i=0;i<p.second;i++){
        result+=p.first;
    }
    st.pop();
} 
reverse(result.begin(),result.end());
return result;
```

}

```
int main(){
    string s="“qddxxxdaaa”";
    string result=remove_K_Consecutive_Identical_Characters(s,3);
    cout<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Result {
    public static String recursiveRemoveKconsuChar(String word, int k) {
        char ch=' ';int count =1;
        for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++) {
            if(word.charAt(i)== ch) {
                count++;
            }else {
                count =1;
            }
            if(count==k) {
                return word.substring(0,i-k+1)+ word.substring(i+1,word.length());
            }
            ch = word.charAt(i);
        }
        return word;
    }

    public static String compressWord(String word, int k) {
        while(true) {
            String ret = recursiveRemoveKconsuChar(word, k);
            if(ret.equals(word)) {
                return ret;
            }
            word = ret;
        }
    }
}

public class RemoveConsicutiveKString {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String result = Result.compressWord("aba", 2);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using regex concepts.

```
String input = "abbcccb";
int k = 3;
input = input.replaceAll("(.)\\1+{"+(k-1)+"}", "");
return input;
```

Regex Explanation:
`(.)\\1+` = any character that is repeating twice. (`\1` in regex denotes the first captured group).
`{k-1}` = QUANTIFIER -> captures specific occurrence of a group. (since two chars are grouped in the above regex, we are using `k-1`).